# How to remove 1 element from array in typescipt?

Tags: javascript

I thought it doing like this:

```js
const months2 = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
console.log(months2.splice(3, 1));
```

output: [ 'June' ]

Comment: i'd look up javascript questions. typescript only helps with the signatures

Answer (score 2):

You actually have it exactly right. `Array.splice` removes elements from the existing array and returns the elements that were removed.

```
const months2 = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
console.log(months2.splice(3, 1)); // Output: ['June']
console.log(months2); // Output: ['Jan', 'March', 'April']
```